# Property 'prop' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TableProp'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component I am trying to pass a prop to. This is my first time seeing this error and from the other posts on it, I have not been able to resolve it on my end.

This is the shortened version of my code:

```
type TableProp = {};

function Table(prop: TableProp)
{
    //...
}

function Test()
{
    const testProp: TableProp = {
        // ...
    }

    return (
        <Table prop={ testProp }/>
    )
}
```

Now when I attempt to use this I get an error where I am setting `prop` for the `Table` component in `Test()`

The error reads:

```
Type '{ prop: TableProp; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TableProp'.
Property 'prop' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TableProp'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 2):

You just update like this:

`<Table {...testProp }/>`